# Counter variable skips forward

Tags: javascript

```
var counter = -1;
var properties = [["Snack", "Meal"], ["Hot", "Cold"], ["Spicy", "Non-Spicy"], ["Vegan", "Non-Vegan"], ["Cheesy", "Non-Cheesy"], ["Creamy", "Non-Creamy"], ["Crunchy", "Non-Crunchy"]];
var button1 = $("#button1");
var button2 = $("#button2");

function letsDoThis() {
    var prop = "";
    counter++;
    console.log(counter);
    button1.html(properties[counter][0]);
    button2.html(properties[counter][1]);
    button1.on("click", function(){
        onClick(button1.html());

    });
    button2.on("click", function(){
        onClick(button2.html());
    });
}

function onClick(prop){
    prop = prop.toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (!data[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            data.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
            console.log("Removing data...");
        }
    }
    if (properties.length != 0) {
        letsDoThis();
    } else {
        letsFinishThis();
    }
}

function letsFinishThis(){

}
```

I know the code is redundant, messy etc.

I want the counter to go forward once on every click. However, what happens is that it moves forward on the first click, and then it goes forward twice. On the third click, it goes all the way to 8 for some reason. It's been boggling me for a while. Any suggestions?

PS. The data variable is in another file.

Comment: Did you trace through your code with the debugger, and/or use breakpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues with your code. I address the one in the title.

```
$(document)ready(function(){
  var counter = 0;
  $(document).on('click','whatwver',function(){
      counter++;
      //do something
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me about some other issues? I'm new to all this.

Answer (score 1):

```
button2.on("click", function(){
    onClick(button2.html());
})
```

Every time you execute `onClick` then it calls `letsDoThis` which adds another click handler.

You want that code to only be called once.

Debugging hint:  Had you added a `console.log` statement into `onClick`, you could have seen it was execute multiple times per element click.